# Class toggle removes other classes

Tags: jquery

Good morning SO,

I am trying to toggle between 3 classes to assign colors to text boxes.  The toggleClass method works for 2 classes but not for 3 so I wrote a function based off of a response I found on SO to how to toggle between 3 classes.  After I hit the ready button to toggle classes the first time, instead of toggling the classes it removes all existing classes and adds the class in the array instead appending one of the 3 classes in the array to the end.  This since the text boxes are targeted by class, this prevents me from being able to click the button to move on to the next class.  How could I change my code to stop it from removing the initial set of classes?

JQuery

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
    
        $('#btn1').click(function() {
            $('.tb1').each(function () {
                var classes = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];
                this.className = classes[($.inArray(this.className, classes) + 1) % classes.length];
            });
        });
    });
```

```css
.tbleft{
    font-size: 63px;
    width: 28%;
    color:white;
    margin-top:.5%
}
.tbcenter{
    font-size: 63px;
    width: 20%;
    color:white;
    margin-top:.5%
}
.green{
    background-color: green;
}
.red{
    background-color: red;
}
.blue{
    background-color:dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<form class="leftform" action="/write" method="post">
       <input class="tb1 tbleft red" id="tb1-1" type="text" name="loads"/>
       <input class="tb1 tbcenter red" id="tb1-2" type="text" name="door"/>
       <input class="tb1 tbcenter red" id="tb1-3" type="text" name="quad"/>
       <input class="btn" id="btn1" type="button" value="Ready"/>
       </form>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4uaor8ka/)

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the below code. I have done some significant changes to rotate the colors:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var classes = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];
  $('#btn1').click(function() {
    $('.tb1').each(function() {
      var current = $(this);
      $(classes).each(function(k, v) {
        if (current.hasClass(v)) {
          var keyNum = k + 1
          if (classes.length == (k + 1)) {
            keyNum = 0
          }
          current.removeClass(v).addClass(classes[keyNum]);
          return false;
        }
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.tbleft {
  font-size: 63px;
  width: 28%;
  color: white;
  margin-top: .5%
}

.tbcenter {
  font-size: 63px;
  width: 20%;
  color: white;
  margin-top: .5%
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="leftform" action="/write" method="post">
  <input class="tb1 tbleft red" id="tb1-1" type="text" name="loads" />
  <input class="tb1 tbcenter red" id="tb1-2" type="text" name="door" />
  <input class="tb1 tbcenter red" id="tb1-3" type="text" name="quad" />
  <input class="btn" id="btn1" type="button" value="Ready" />
</form>
```

Comment: You’re welcome, If it helped you, please [upvote and accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) Happy Coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 variables called previousClass and newClass:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var previousClass = "red", newClass = "red";
    var classes = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];

    $('#btn1').click(function () {
        previousClass = newClass;
        newClass = classes[($.inArray(previousClass, classes) + 1) % classes.length];

        $('.tb1').each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass(previousClass).addClass(newClass);
        });
    });
});
```

here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lrjsheot/1/

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the response here.  Based on what Konrad mentioned I started playing with addClass and removeClass and your code incorporates it into exactly what I wanted just as Milan Chheda's did.  Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are stripping all the classes off the elements is because those that are not in the array will also be stripped out.

Since `red` is also guaranteed to be in your `classes` list, we can:

1. Return the color class by filtering through the classList
2. Get new color based on the returned color class
3. Use `classList.remove()` to remove old class
4. Use `classList. add()` to add new class

Of course, this means that the browser [needs to support the modern `DOMTokenList` API](http://caniuse.com/#search=classlist).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var classes = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];

  $('#btn1').click(function() {
    $('.tb1').each(function() {
      // Retrieve color classes from classList by checking if it is in classes array
      var colorClass = [].filter.call(this.classList, function(cls) {
        return classes.indexOf(cls) > -1;
      })[0];
      
      // Get new color
      var newColorClass = classes[($.inArray(colorClass, classes) + 1) % classes.length];
      
      // Remove old class, add new class
      this.classList.remove(colorClass);
      this.classList.add(newColorClass);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.tbleft {
  font-size: 63px;
  width: 28%;
  color: white;
  margin-top: .5%
}

.tbcenter {
  font-size: 63px;
  width: 20%;
  color: white;
  margin-top: .5%
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="leftform" action="/write" method="post">
  <input class="tb1 tbleft red" id="tb1-1" type="text" name="loads" />
  <input class="tb1 tbcenter red" id="tb1-2" type="text" name="door" />
  <input class="tb1 tbcenter red" id="tb1-3" type="text" name="quad" />
  <input class="btn" id="btn1" type="button" value="Ready" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use data attributes. Just add another color to data-colors attribute.

```js
var colorsStr = $('#btn1').data('colors');
var colorsArr = colorsStr.split(',').reverse();
var index = colorsArr.length - 1;

$('#btn1').click(function() {

  if (index < 0) index = colorsArr.length - 1;
  
  $.each($('.tb1'), function(key, val) {
    $(val).css('background-color', colorsArr[index]);
  })

  index -= 1;
});
```

```css
.tbleft{
    font-size: 63px;
    width: 28%;
    color:white;
    margin-top:.5%
}
.tbcenter{
    font-size: 63px;
    width: 20%;
    color:white;
    margin-top:.5%
}
.red{
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="leftform" action="/write" method="post">
  <input class="tb1 tbleft red" id="tb1-1" type="text" name="loads"/>
  <input class="tb1 tbcenter red" id="tb1-2" type="text" name="door"/>
  <input class="tb1 tbcenter red" id="tb1-3" type="text" name="quad"/>
  <input class="btn" id="btn1" type="button" value="Ready" data-colors="green, blue, red"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using `this.className`, try with `$(this).addClass()` and `$(this).removeClass()`.

`this.className` overwrites all classes you have for that element. 
Instead, you want to remove only the colour class, and add a new one.